# Getting the current learning rate from a tf.train.AdamOptimizer

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like print out the learning rate for each training step of my nn.

I know that Adam has an adaptive learning rate, but is there a way i can see this (for visualization in tensorboard)

Comment: By quickly reading the code, you can get tr: print sess.run(adam_op._lr_t), after having adam_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1, beta1=0.5, beta2=0.5)
, train_op = adam_op.minimize(cost). However, it's not sure its working in your code. Can you qickly test?

Comment: Side note: The right way to think about adam is not as learning rate (scaling the gradients), but as a step size. The `learning_rate` you pass in is the maximum step size (per parameter), Adam takes steps up to that size, depending on how consistent the gradient is.

Comment: OK @mdaoust, but then how can I obtain the learning rate at each step? I tried Sung Kim suggestion but does not work, as it returns a flat line. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All the optimizers have a private variable that holds the value of a learning rate.

In [adagrad](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/training/adagrad.py#L55) and [gradient descent](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/training/gradient_descent.py#L43) it is called `self._learning_rate`. In [adam](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L86) it is `self._lr`.

So you will just need to print `sess.run(optimizer._lr)` to get this value. Sess.run is needed because they are tensors.

Comment: Note in tf2.x, with a learning rate schedule in use, you should use: (for ADAM) `lr = optimizer._decayed_lr(tf.float32)`

Answer (score 12):

Sung Kim suggestion worked for me, my exact steps were:

```
lr = 0.1
step_rate = 1000
decay = 0.95

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
increment_global_step = tf.assign(global_step, global_step + 1)
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(lr, global_step, step_rate, decay, staircase=True)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, epsilon=0.01)
trainer = optimizer.minimize(loss_function)

# Some code here

print('Learning rate: %f' % (sess.run(trainer ._lr)))
```

Comment: I use `GradientDescentOptimizer` and use `self._learning_rate`. It does not work for me.  I get error `AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute '_learning_rate'`

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest thing you can do is subclass the optimizer.

It has several methods, that I guess get dispatched to based on variable type. Regular Dense variables seem to go through `_apply_dense`. This solution won't work for sparse or other things.

If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L137) you can see that it's storing the `m` and `t` EMAs in these "slots". So something like this seems do it:

```py
class MyAdam(tf.train.AdamOptimizer):
    def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        m = self.get_slot(var, "m")
        v = self.get_slot(var, "v")

        m_hat = m/(1-self._beta1_power)
        v_hat = v/(1-self._beta2_power)

        step = m_hat/(v_hat**0.5 + self._epsilon_t)

        # Use a histogram summary to monitor it during training.
        tf.summary.histogram("hist", step) 

        return super(MyAdam,self)._apply_dense(grad, var)
```

`step` here will be in the interval [-1,1], that's what gets multiplied by the learning rate, to determines the actual step applied to the parameters.

There's often no node in the graph for it because there is one big `training_ops.apply_adam` that does everything.

Here I'm just creating a histogram summary from it. But you could stick it in a dictionary attached to the object and read it later or do whatever you want with it.

Droping that into [`mnist_deep.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py), and adding some summaries to the training loop:

```
all_summaries = tf.summary.merge_all()  
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/Adam")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy,summaries = sess.run(
                [accuracy,all_summaries],
                feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], 
                           keep_prob: 1.0})
            file_writer.add_summary(summaries, i)
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
       train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

Produces the following figure in TensorBoard:

[image: TensorBoard Histogram tab, showing 8 different histogram plots]

Comment: Due to resource constraint I have to explicitly place my network onto different GPUs, and this subclassing hack gives me an error: `Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:1' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available`. Removing the `tf.summary.histogram` line will remove the complaint.

Comment: Later versions of Tensorflow have a slightly different way of accessing the beta variables.

Answer (score 4):

In `Tensorflow 2`:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(learning_rate=0.1)  # or any other optimizer
print(optimizer.learning_rate.numpy())  # or print(optimizer.lr.numpy())
```

Note: This gives you the base learning rate. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58151051/4315914) for more details on adaptive learning rates.

Comment: When I call ````print(model.optimizer.learning_rate)```` as you suggested, I am getting ````<keras.optimizer_v2.learning_rate_schedule.ExponentialDecay object at 0x0000021BDEF68F70>````. If I add ````numpy()````. then I receive ````'ExponentialDecay' object has no attribute 'numpy'````

Comment: They might've checked the object signature. You might wanna take a look at it's definition on it's source codes.

Comment: If you use a scheduler like `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay`, [call this object with the current training step as argument](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule).

Answer (score 3):

In TensorFlow sources current lr for Adam optimizer calculates like:

```
    lr = (lr_t * math_ops.sqrt(1 - beta2_power) / (1 - beta1_power))
```

So, try it:

```
    current_lr = (optimizer._lr_t * tf.sqrt(1 - 
    optimizer._beta2_power) / (1 - optimizer._beta1_power))

    eval_current_lr = sess.run(current_lr)
```

Comment: in the code your beta2_power and beta1_power seems to be switched , compared to the tf sources you wrote above

Answer (score 0):

For Tensorflow 2 using `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule` inspired by [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39782#issuecomment-866184651) comment:

```
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.CosineDecay(learning_rate, total_steps)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr_schedule)
print(optimizer.lr(optimizer.iterations))
```