# Learning rate doesn't change for AdamOptimizer in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to see how the learning rate changes during training (print it out or create a summary and visualize it in tensorboard).

Here is a code snippet from what I have so far:

```py
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=global_step)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(0, 10000):
   sess.run(train_op)
   print sess.run(optimizer._lr_t)
```

If I run the code I constantly get the initial learning rate (1e-3) i.e. I see no change.

What is a correct way for getting the learning rate at every step?

I would like to add that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990476/getting-the-current-learning-rate-from-a-tf-train-adamoptimizer) is really similar to mine. However, I cannot post my findings in the comment section there since I do not have enough rep.

Answer (score 4):

I was asking myself the exact same question, and wondering why wouldn't it change. By looking at the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980v8.pdf) (page 2), one sees that the `self._lr` stepsize (designed with `alpha` in the paper) is required by the algorithm, but never updated. We also see that there is an `alpha_t` that is updated for every `t` step, and should correspond to the `self._lr_t` attribute. But in fact, as you observe, **evaluating the value for the `self._lr_t` tensor at any point during the training returns always the initial value, that is, `_lr`**.

So your question, as I understood it, is **how to get the `alpha_t` for TensorFlow's AdamOptimizer as described in section 2 of the paper and in the corresponding [TF v1.2 API page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer)**:

> `alpha_t = alpha * sqrt(1-beta_2_t) / (1-beta_1_t)`

#### BACKGROUND

As you observed, the `_lr_t` tensor doesn't change thorough the training, which may lead to the false conclusion that the optimizer doesn't adapt (this can be easily tested by switching to the *vanilla* `GradientDescentOptimizer` with the same `alpha`). And, in fact, other values do change: a quick look at the optimizer's `__dict__` shows the following keys: `['_epsilon_t', '_lr', '_beta1_t', '_lr_t', '_beta1', '_beta1_power', '_beta2', '_updated_lr', '_name', '_use_locking', '_beta2_t', '_beta2_power', '_epsilon', '_slots']`.

By inspecting them through training, I noticed that **only `_beta1_power`, `_beta2_power` and the `_slots` get updated**.

Further inspecting [the optimizer's code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/927f811b0303e51126531c135f8b093383de2d6d/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L211), in line 211, we see the following update:

```
update_beta1 = self._beta1_power.assign(
        self._beta1_power * self._beta1_t,
        use_locking=self._use_locking)
```

Which basically means that `_beta1_power`, which is [initialized with `_beta1`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/927f811b0303e51126531c135f8b093383de2d6d/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L120), will be multiplied by `_beta_1_t` after every iteration, which [is also initialized with `beta_1_t`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/927f811b0303e51126531c135f8b093383de2d6d/tensorflow/python/training/adam.py#L133).

But here comes the confusing part: **`_beta1_t` and `_beta2_t` never get updated**, so effectively they hold the initial values (`_beta1`and `_beta2`) through the whole training, contradicting the notation of the paper in a similar fashion as `_lr` and `lr_t` do. *I guess this is for a reason but I personally don't know why, in any case this are protected/private attributes of the implementation (as they start with an underscore) and don't belong to the public interface (they may even change among TF versions).*

So after this small background we can see that `_beta_1_power` and `_beta_2_power` are the original beta values exponentiated to the current training step, that is, the equivalent to the variables referred with `beta_t`in the paper. Going back to the definition of `alpha_t` in the section 2 of the paper, we see that, with this information, it should be pretty straightforward to implement:

#### SOLUTION

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
# rest of the graph...

# ... somewhere in your session
# note that a0 comes from a scalar, whereas bb1 and bb2 come from tensors and thus have to be evaluated
a0, bb1, bb2 = optimizer._lr, optimizer._beta1_power.eval(), optimizer._beta2_power.eval()
at = a0* (1-bb2)**0.5 /(1-bb1)
print(at)
```

The variable `at` holds the `alpha_t` for the current training step.

#### DISCLAIMER

I couldn't find a cleaner way of getting this value by just using the optimizer's interface, but please let me know if it exists one! I guess there is none, which actually puts into question the usefulness of plotting `alpha_t`, since **it does not depend on the data**.

Also, to complete this information, section 2 of the paper also gives the formula for the weight updates, which is much more telling, but also more plot-intensive. For a very nice and good-looking implementation of that, you may want to take a look at [this nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688307/4511978) from the post that you linked.

Hope it helps! Cheers,
Andres

Comment: Is there an update to this answer for Tensorflow 2?