# Is there a way to get the current learning rate from an Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tpu

I would like to keep track of the learning rate while training with an `Estimator` (a `TPUEstimator` on a TPU, of all things). I am experimenting with the [Colab MNIST example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/mnist_tpuestimator.ipynb). I figured I would create a training hook, which would log the learning rate. Here is my code:

```py
class TrainHook(tf.train.SessionRunHook):
    def __init__(self, optimizer):
        self.optimizer = optimizer

    def after_create_session(self, session, coord):
        self.session = session

    def before_run(self, run_context):
        # optimizer is a CrossShardOptimizer (see notebook), hence ._opt
        logger.info('Learning rate is {}'.format(
            self.optimizer._opt._lr.eval(session=self.session))
```

`optimizer` was created like this in `model_fn` (copied from the notebook):

```py
step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
lr = 0.0001 + tf.train.exponential_decay(0.01, step, 2000//8, 1/math.e)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
if params['use_tpu']:
    optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(optimizer)
```

Unfortunately, when I run this code, I get the following error: "Error recorded from training_loop: Operation 'add_1' has been marked as not fetchable." Apparently _opt._lr is an add_1 operation, because of `exponential_decay`. At least on the TPU; when I install regular Tensorflow on my laptop, it's an `add` operator; could this be the difference?

[I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990476/getting-the-current-learning-rate-from-a-tf-train-adamoptimizer) that even if I could get it, `_lr` is not the current, but the base learning rate. But it's a start. :)

Note: `_lr` and `_lr_t` behaves identically in that both result in the error above.

I use tensorflow v1.14.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use `optimizer.variables()`? see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/AdamOptimizer#variables

Comment: @Tyler No, that works, and I can run all the tensors therein. However, the learning rate is not among the variables, only the betas... (btw. sorry for the late answer)

Comment: @DavidNemeskey hi did you get the answer? I have the same question, please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1024 I haven't got any answers, but it doesn't really matter as I have long since switched to PyTorch. So I am sorry, but I cannot really help.